# Trouble understanding how dependent current sources affect a circuit (Two-port networks)

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement, current-source, nodal-analysis

While reviewing a problem from my recent test on two-port networks I noticed that it made its way online.

When someone was explaining the solution they utilized a point that I just completely missed. I wanted to ask about it here.

The line was in reference to this section of the circuit:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYSpb.png)

[image: Embedded Image of Circuit]

The solution online noted that the current flowing from the top-right node in this picture was the current flowing in (I_1) minus the current flowing through the 25 Ohm branch (2V_1), or I_1 - 2V_1.

**My main question here** is to try and take away some sort of generalization that I missed during my basic circuits class. Does the dependent current source dictate the current across the entire branch? Doesn't that mean the voltage across the 25 Ohm resistor is always known to be 50V_1?

Sorry if this seems like too basic a question, but apparently between a poor circuits foundation and the circumstances we find ourselves in I am failing to understand something I should have learned last year!